# How to cut/yank half of a Vim "inner" or "block" object

Tags: vim

I'm sure there must be some simple way to e.g. yank only the portion of an inner context that starts with the cursor, but haven't found anything.
For example

```
fcn(arg1, arg2, fcn2(x, y), arg4)
              ^-cursor here
```

How do I reduce this to

```
fcn(arg1, arg2)
```

in one command, without having to e.g. count intervening parentheses?

Edit:
The accepted answer establishes some good alternate ways of doing what I want to do, by using the "d])" pattern, or repeating "dt]", but there seems to be no way in (vanilla) Vim to leverage the full power of Text objects in combination with a starting cursor position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `])`. From `:h ])`:

```
                        ])
])          go to [count] next unmatched ')'.
            |exclusive| motion.
```

So `y])` to yank and `c])` to cut.

Other motion of interest would be `[(` (previous unmatched `(`), `]}` (next unmatched `}`), …

---

*Edit*: missed the part about sentences and paragraphs.

You can use `)` to go to the end of s sentence and `(` to go to the beginning of it, so `d)` deletes from the cursor to the next sentence.
`{`/`}` do the same for paragraphs.

---

As for going to the next square bracket I *think* you could use matchit.vim, but it's been a while since I last used it. Somehow else might know more about it.

Comment: I guess this covers most useful cases, but not all cases where "inner" is useful - I can't do `c]]` for square brackets, or `c]s` for sentence or `c]p` for paragraph.

Comment: @KristofferSjöö maybe a better sample would be nice then. I solve this kind of stuff with `dt]` and repeat it if needed with `.` However this solution is the way to go for most use-cases.

Comment: Easy and useful. Vim always has something to surprise me.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion, @DoktorOSwaldo. That's useful, although it doesn't work if the closing bracket is on a different line.

Comment: @KristofferSjöö then you can use `d/]<CR>` and then `dn` (which is all a little bit slow) you could speed that up with [easymotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion).

Comment: Also: I'm a SE newbie so I'm not sure what the proper way is to provide a better sample - do I Edit the original post, with an explicit "edit:" addendum? Should I rewrite the question? Or post a new one?

Comment: @KristofferSjöö the important thing is to not lose information. To be clear, there is a fine question with a really good answer. If your rewrite would render the answer invalid, do not do that. Then a new question (if the title would also remove the whole question which is answered), or an addendum (the problem has changed) would be fine. But in your case a rewrite should be fine. And welcome to SO!

Comment: @KristofferSjöö: Sorry missed the part about sentences & paragraphs, edited my answer.